# Is it more optimal to use glCullFace or glFrontFace in a render loop?

Tags: c++, performance, opengl, graphics

Let's say I want to use back-face culling and have two meshes; one of which uses a clockwise draw order for its points, and the other counterclockwise. After calling `glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)`, I have two options for drawing both:

1. I could call `glCullFace(GL_BACK)` outside the render loop, and then switch between `glFrontFace(GL_CW)` and `glFrontFace(GL_CCW)` before drawing each mesh in my render loop.
2. I could call `glFrontFace(GL_CW)` outside the render loop, and then switch between `glCullFace(GL_BACK)` and `glCullFace(GL_FRONT)` before drawing each mesh in my render loop.

I would assume, to properly describe the nature of each mesh in my program, that using the first option would be better. However, I was wondering if there were any performance differences that would make using the second option preferable?

Comment: I can't imagine that the difference would be worth worrying about—but if you're worried about it, you should measure it.

Comment: Or you could reverse the vertex order in one of the meshes and then do neither.